# Django Rest Framework - automatically annotate queryset

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I use one `Serializer` in many different places in my project. I need to use one annotation but the problem is that I don't want to annotate it in all views so I would like to do universal annotation in the `Serializer` itself.

It is possible?

Now I need to do this before every serialization:

```
City.objects....filter....annotate(
                number_of_users_here_now=Count('current_userprofiles'))
```

I tried:

```
class NumberOfUsersInCityNowField(serializers.Field):
    def to_native(self, value):
        count = value.annotate(
            number_of_users_here_now=Count('current_userprofiles'))['current_userprofiles__count']
        return count


class CityMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number_of_users_here_now = NumberOfUsersInCityNowField()

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('place_id', 'lat', 'lng', 'number_of_users_here_now', 'formatted_address')
```

This `Serializer` returns:

> AttributeError at /api/ajax-check-trip-creation Got AttributeError
>   when attempting to get a value for field `number_of_users_here_now` on
>   serializer `CityMapSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `City` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'City' object has no attribute
>   'number_of_users_here_now'.

**EDIT**

```
class NumberOfUsersInCityNowField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return City.objects.annotate(
        number_of_users_here_now=Count('current_userprofiles'))

class CityMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # number_of_users_here_now = serializers.IntegerField()
    number_of_users_here_now = NumberOfUsersInCityNowField()
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('place_id', 'lat', 'lng', 'number_of_users_here_now', 'formatted_address')
```

But

```
serializers.CityMapSerializer(City.objects.all()[:3],many=True).data
```

still returns:

```
AttributeError: 'City' object has no attribute 'number_of_users_here_now'
```

Comment: you have the same field name in the model?

Comment: No, that's not a native field. I need to add count of userprofiles for each city.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use queryset's `count` method with [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class CityMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number_of_users_here_now = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_number_of_users_here_now (self, obj):
        return obj.current_userprofiles.count()
```

**UPD**

Also to avoid n+1 queries you can try to implement `get_queryset` method of `NumberOfUsersInCityNowField` serializer:

```
class NumberOfUsersInCityNowField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return City.objects.annotate(
        number_of_users_here_now=Count('current_userprofiles'))['current_userprofiles__count']
```

Comment: I wan't to avoid doing this since it access the database for every city, not just once as it is with annotating.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik yes you are right, try to inherited from `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and override `get_queryset` method.

Comment: Your solution seems to be what I want but unfortunately it returns the same error. I've added the code at the bottom of the question.

Comment: The City is a foreign key in model UserProfile with related_name='current_userprofiles'

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik sorry, cannot suggest you anything better. Iif you will not find the solution probably you should try mixin class which implements annotation and add it to all your view.